# Why $Kom(\mathcal{A})$ may not be triangulated, while $D(\mathcal{A})$ may not be abelian?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category, let $Kom(\mathcal{A})$ be the category of complex with a shift functor $T$, and Let $D(\mathcal{A})$ be the derived category of $\mathcal{A}$.

Why:

> (1) $Kom(\mathcal{A})$ may not be a triangulated category?
>
> (2) $D(\mathcal{A})$ may not be an abelian category?

I am quite new to those derived category stuff, so any intuitions behind the counterexamples are also very welcome, and will be very important for me to understand these concepts.

Comment: For a) it might be helpful to notice that any morphism $X \to Y$ in a tiangulated category can be completed to a distinguished triangle $X \to Y \to Z \to X[1].$

Comment: For (2) see also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/189769/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (2) see [MO/15658](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15658/how-do-i-know-the-derived-category-is-not-abelian).

(1) isn't well-defined, because a triangulated category is not just a category with extra properties. It also comes equipped with extra structure, namely the class of distinguished triangles. A more precise question would include a definition of the distinguished triangles and then ask why it doesn't satisfy the axioms of a triangulated category. Or are you interested in pathological / arbitrary triangulated structures?

Comment: Well, since there typically are many non-split monorphisms in Kom(A) there is little hope to find any exotic triangulated structures.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Thank you for your link to the first question, I think combining with the comment given by Martin above, it answers my second question as well, because "Every monomorphism in a triangulated category splits", and in order to make $Kom(A)$ triangulated, we should put some conditions on $A$.